# Why are Jill and Tim getting... intimate in "Out of the Shelter"?

Tags: david-lodge, out-of-the-shelter

In the beginning of David Lodge's *Out of the Shelter*, right before

> Jill and her mother are killed by the bomb,

Jill and Tim are getting a little intimate... at the age of what looks like six.

> — You're not going away tomorrow, are you Daddy? said Jill, keeping her arms round his neck so he couldn't stand up straight.
>   — Not straightaway, no, my precious.
>   — Not ever?
>   — You have a nice sleep now, my pet, or you'll be too tired to play with me in the morning.
>   — Can Timothy sleep in my bunk?
>   — We usually let them, said Auntie Nora.
>   — I suppose it's all right, if he's going to marry you, said Uncle Jack, and the grown-ups laughed.
>   [...]
>   The guns sounded faint now, a long way off. He pulled down his pyjama trousers and Jill wriggled beside him as she pulled up the skirt of her nightie. Then he felt her cool soft fingers on his thing and with his own finger he felt for the little crease between her legs. He was warm and safe and sleepy. He hoped that there would be another raid the next night.

Why are Jill and Tim doing this? What's the point of this scene?